# Can auto-format break at hyphens?

Tags: vimrc, formatting

I write my email in `vim`, which dynamically inserts newlines after 72 characters.

```
formatoptions=awtcql
```

This works nicely, breaking at spaces. However, is there a way to make it break at hyphens as well?

Answer (score 3):

[`:help 'textwidth'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27textwidth%27) is documented as:

> Maximum width of text that is being inserted.  A longer line will be broken
>   after white space to get this width.

Reading [`:help fo-table`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#fo%2dtable), it seems
there is only one option to change this:

```
m       Also break at a multi-byte character above 255.  This is useful for
        Asian text where every character is a word on its own.
```

Which brings us to a possible workaround – you can use the en dash (U+2013) or
another non-ascii character instead of a normal hyphen (U+002D):

```
:set formatoptions+=m
:inoremap - –
```

It's a bit ugly, but may work in your case.

---

A second – more complicated – solution can also be found in `:help
textwidth`:

```
When 'formatexpr' is set it will be used to break the line.
```

See [`:help 'formatexpr'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatexpr%27) for
some details. Personally, I've never been able to get this to work quite right
for "live formatting" (as opposed to `gq` formatting), but it should be possible
(I never tried very hard).

---

And lastly, you can use `:%!` or [`'formatprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatprg%27)
to run an external command over the text. This is not ideal as you'll have to
run this manually every time, but it's an option (you could also just write a
Vimscript command for this though).

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote for suggesting that en dashes could replace hyphens. :p However, +1 for the three thorough suggestions. I'm on vacation at the moment, but I'll test out `formatexpr` and report back when I get a chance.

Comment: @Sparhawk Yeah, I did say it's ugly ;-) Note that you could use *any* character above 255, and that you can easily replace them with hyphens with something like `:%s/–$/-/`. Out of all the possible options, it's certainly the *easiest*.

Comment: Haha… okay then. I'd prefer not to do that, because it's not *automatic*. i.e. I'd type with the wrong character, then have to remember to substitute, then what if I wanted to add words somewhere? (And if I *did* use en-dashes in proper locations, I'd accidentally sub them out.) I also had a look at `formatexpr`, but I don't really understand how to use it. Also, it's empty by default, and says "When this option is empty 'formatprg' is used." Hence, I wonder if either of these could be tweaked to break on hyphens instead?